# Describe the dynamics of a fluctuating vector

Tags: vectors, correlation-functions, data-analysis, visualization, stochastic-processes

I have a time series for the $\mathbf{v}(t) = (x,y,z)$ components of a vector quantity. It is fluctuating in time, and has a non-trivial autocorrelation function which I want to somehow elucidate. The system is anisotropic and asymmetric in the x-y plane, so in the end I can obtain three distinct autocorrelation functions:

$$
\begin{align}
    A_{xx}(t) &= \langle x(t)x(0) \rangle\\
    A_{yy}(t) &= \langle y(t)y(0) \rangle\\
    A_{zz}(t) &= \langle z(t)z(0) \rangle
\end{align}
$$
as well as two cross-correlations

$$
\begin{align}
    A_{xy}(t) &= \langle x(t)y(0) \rangle\\
    A_{yx}(t) &= \langle y(t)x(0) \rangle
\end{align}
$$

That is quite a bit of data and I am still unable to grasp how my vector moves, so I am looking for ideas on how to synthesize/analyse the data. Would it make sense to construct a time-dependent tensor

$$
A(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
\langle x(t)x(0)\rangle & \langle x(t)y(0)\rangle & 0\\
\langle y(t)x(0)\rangle & \langle y(t)y(0)\rangle & 0\\
0 & 0 & \langle z(t)z(0)\rangle \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and then diagonalize it using standard means, which would give 3 autocorrelations of the principal axes, plus some time dependent tilt angle $\theta(t)$?

I can also obtain the cross-product correlation
$$
\langle \mathbf{v}(t)\times \mathbf{v}(0) \rangle = \langle x(t)y(0) - y(t)x(0)\rangle \mathbf{\hat{z}}
$$
which looks like a physically sensible quantity but I am still having a hard time understanding the motion. By the way, the average $\langle x\rangle = \langle y\rangle = \langle z\rangle = 0$.

Do you have any ideas on how to analyze/visualize such data to obtain more insight about the motion?

Comment: +1 Welcome to Physics SE! Do you model [brownian  motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion#/media/File:Brownian_hierarchical.svg). A map (x,y) is linked. Now you are asking for the plots of correlation functions? [Charles Martin covers the math](https://calculatedcontent.com/2013/08/01/causality-correlation-and-brownian-motion/)

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to construct the vector $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ for all times $t$, given only certain averages (auto-correlation functions in this case). Averaging operation usually always results in loss of detailed information, and I doubt you will be able to reconstruct the detailed dynamics of the vector knowing only averages.

Comment: Thanks Deep, but no, I am doing the exact opposite. I have the data [x(t), y(t), z(t)], and I can calculate any correlations from it. Unfortunately, this results in a lot of data, at least 5 graphs, so I'm trying to simplify the result.

Comment: Ok, but simplify towards what end? What is the statistical question you intend to answer? Do you want know average motion? Do you want to elucidate history dependence? Or something else? That will decide what auto-correlation function you must calculate. Also why do you say "...unable to grasp how my vector moves..." when you do have time series data for the vector?

Answer (score 0):

In statistics Box et al. developed the so called *time series analysis*. You could look into that. Here a simple [intro](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54276-time-series-analysis-and-forecast).

- I would definitely try to understand the behavior by looking at the time and frequency structure of the signal. The Fourier transform allows you to identify periodicities.
- Substrat your model from the signal to identify further structure.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to offer practical advice on the numerical analysis, but if the auto-correlation functions may be found, then you may be able to determine if the dynamics is already well known.

For example, *white noise* is characterised by the correlation function,

$$\langle v_i(t_1)v_j(t_2)\rangle \sim \delta_{ij}\delta(t_2-t_1)$$

which gives rise to a variance in the position linearly dependent on $t$. So, if you can determine something close to a closed form expression from the data, you may be able to identify a known type of noise/process.

Furthermore, thanks to the Wiener–Khinchin theorem, the correlation is related to the Fourier transform of the power spectral density. A closed form expression is not required for this, as you can simply perform a discrete numerical Fourier transform. It may be that the spectral density is more useful in identifying the dynamics, if they are known at all.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Well I already have all the autocorrelation functions, as well as the two cross-correlation functions. That leaves me with 5 graphs describing the motion of one 3D vector. I was thinking that maybe the coordinates could be diagonalized/normalized/strained somehow so that I only have 3 graphs? I have tried looking for eigenvalues, but they seem to depend on time as well, so it's not helping much.

Comment: You might try a principal component analysis on all your data to rank the directions by from the most variance to the least and see if anything interesting happens.

Answer (score 0):

I may have come up with a solution. Let us focus on the x-y plane only, where the data is cross-correlated. Let us pick some random starting point $(x(0), y(0))$ and try to predict the the future position by

$$
x(t) = g_{11}(t)x(0) + g_{12}(t)y(0) + W_x(t)\\
y(t) = g_{21}(t)x(0) + g_{22}(t)y(0) + W_y(t)
$$

where $(W_x, W_y)$ is stochastic noise and $g_{ij}(t)$ are some deterministic correlation functions that I propose to obtain in the following manner:
$$
\langle x(t) x(0) \rangle = g_{11}(t)\langle x(0)^2 \rangle + g_{12}(t) \langle y(0)x(0)\rangle\\
\langle x(t) y(0) \rangle = g_{11}(t)\langle x(0)y(0) \rangle + g_{12}(t) \langle y(0)^2\rangle\\
$$
We can solve this to obtain
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
g_{11}(t) \\ g_{12}(t)
\end{pmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{\langle x^2 \rangle \langle y^2 \rangle - \langle xy \rangle^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle y^2\rangle  & -\langle xy \rangle \\
-\langle xy\rangle  & \langle x^2 \rangle \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\langle x(t)x(0) \rangle \\ \langle x(t)y(0) \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and similarly for $g_{21}, g_{22}$. Then I select some points on a circle and plot Eq. 1 (without the noise), to show how the vector relaxes on average:

[image: phase space in shear plane]

[image]